# Using custom template removes text from button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to make a button style where a user hovers over the mouse it changes it's background to an image I set but when I use this style it also removes the text (content)

**Here is the Styling I use**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="StartButton_Style">

        <Setter Property="Background">

            <!-- Background image (dark one)-->
            <Setter.Value>

                <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\yosi1\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Classic Story Launcher\Resources\Start_Button_Nornal.png"/>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Candara"/>

        <Setter Property="FontSize"   Value="40"/>

        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFA48B60"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>


                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <!-- Triggers an event when the user hovers the mouse over the button-->
        <Style.Triggers>

            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">

                <!-- Chagnes the background images to notify the user that his mouse is over the button -->
                <Setter Property="Background">

                    <Setter.Value>

                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\yosi1\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Classic Story Launcher\Resources\Start_Button_Click.png"/>

                    </Setter.Value>

                </Setter>

            </Trigger>

        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
```

**And here is the button element which uses the styling**

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" Content="START" Margin="0,34,0,0" Style="{StaticResource StartButton_Style}"/>
```

Comment: In the ControlTemplate, add a Grid, put the Border in it and after the border (on top of the border) add a <ContentPresenter/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `ContentPresenter` to your template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="StartButton_Style">
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\yosi1\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Classic Story Launcher\Resources\Start_Button_Nornal.png"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Candara"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize"   Value="40"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFA48B60"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\yosi1\OneDrive\מסמכים\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Classic Story Launcher\Resources\Start_Button_Click.png"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you very much this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you give me a link to a webpage where I can read more about it ?